Proof mistake of: $M_0A(G) = B(G)$ for a locally compact group
Let $G$ be a locally compact group with Haar measure $\mu$, and $B(G),A(G),C_r^*(G),L(G)$ be its Fourier-Stieltjes algebra, Fourier algebra, group $C^* $-algerba and von Neumann algebra respectively. For $\varphi \in L^\infty(G)$ consider the maps
$$
M_\varphi: A(G) \rightarrow A(G), \,  \psi \mapsto \varphi\psi \quad \text{ for all } \psi \in A(G),
$$
$$
m_\varphi: C_r^*(G) \rightarrow C_r^*(G), \,  f \mapsto \varphi f \quad \text{ for all } f \in C_r^*(G).
$$
$$
\overline{m_\varphi}: L(G) \rightarrow L(G), \,  f \mapsto \varphi f \quad \text{ for all } f \in L(G).
$$
They are related in the following ways:
Proposition 1 ([1, Proposition 3.2]) Let $\varphi \in L^\infty(G)$, then $M_\varphi$ is well defined and completely bounded if and only if $\overline{m_\varphi}$ is well defined and completely bounded. Moreover, their c.b. norms coincide.
If $\varphi \in L^\infty(G)$ satisfies these properties, it is said to be a completely bounded multiplier and the set of all such functions is denoted by $M_0A(G)$.
Proposition 2 ([1, Theorem 2.2]) Let $\varphi \in L^\infty(G)$, the following are equivalent:

$\varphi \in B(G)$;
$m_\varphi: C_r^*(G) \rightarrow C_r^*(G)$ is bounded;
$m_\varphi: C_r^*(G) \rightarrow C_r^*(G)$ is completely bounded;

From my understanding, this two results would imply $M_0A(G) = B(G)$, which known to be false (see for example [2]).
Fake Proof: It is well-known that $B(G) \subseteq M_0A(G)$, so the deal is to "prove" the converse. Let $\varphi \in M_0A(G)$, then $\overline{m_\varphi}: L(G) \rightarrow L(G)$ is well-defined and c.b. by Proposition 1. We can see that $C_r^*(G) \subseteq L(G)$ is invariant for  $\overline{m_\varphi}$, indeed if $f \in C_c(G)$, then $\overline{m_\varphi}(f) = \varphi f \in C_c(G)$ and since $f \in C_r^*(G)$ is the norm limit of elements in $C_c(G)$, then $\overline{m_\varphi}(f) \in C_r^*(G)$.
We then have that
$$
\overline{m_\varphi}|_{C_r^*(G)} = m_\varphi : C_r^*(G) \rightarrow C_r^*(G)
$$
is (completely) bounded which by Proposition 2 gives $\varphi \in B(G)$.

The most important step was the proof that $\overline{m_\varphi}|_{C_r^*(G)} = m_\varphi$, which seems correct to me. However, it has to be the flawed part. Can anyone point out the mistake in my proof?


[1] Renault, Jean, The Fourier algebra of a measured groupoid and its multipliers, J. Funct. Anal. 145, No. 2, 455-490 (1997). ZBL0874.43003.
[2] de Cannière, Jean; Haagerup, Uffe, Multipliers of the Fourier algebras of some simple Lie groups and their discrete subgroups, Am. J. Math. 107, 455-500 (1985). ZBL0577.43002.

I’m not an expert on Fourier algebras and Fourier multipliers. Just from a cursory glance, however, it seems to me the issue is the assertion that $f \in C_c(G)$ implies $\varphi f \in C_c(G)$. Certainly $\varphi f$ is compactly supported, but why should it be continuous?

Oh, nvm, $M_0A(G) = B(G)$ should not be true for discrete groups $G$ unless $G$ is amenable either, so that’s not the only issue. I went through [1], and the actual issue is simpler. You mis-cited Theorem 2.2. It says $\varphi \in B(G)$ iff $m_\varphi$ is bounded (or equivalently completely bounded) as an operator on the full group $C^\ast$-algebra $C^\ast(G)$ (which is denoted by $C^\ast_\mu(G)$ in [1]), instead of the reduced group $C^\ast$-algebra $C^\ast_r(G)$ (which is denoted by $C^\ast_{red}(G)$ in [1]). It is the reduced group $C^\ast$-algebra that is a subalgebra of $VN(G)$…

… while, indeed, only for amenable $G$ would you have $C^\ast(G) = C^\ast_r(G)$ (at least for discrete $G$, I don’t know much about general LCH groups). So, your argument would only work for amenable discrete $G$, in which case $M_0A(G) = B(G)$ is actually true and there’s no contradiction.

Indeed, you are right. I made a confusion with the definition $C_\mu^(G)$ I understood wrongly that it would yield the reduced $C^$-algebra if we considered $\mu$ to have full support on the unit space. But of course when the unit space is just a point, meaning we are dealing with a group, the algebra in question is indeed $C^*(G)$. Thank you a lot.
